# VS2015 crashes on start up in windows10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Recently i installed VS2015 in windows10. But visual studio is crashed and closed every time when i opening it.

[image: Screenshot - VS2015 Crashes]

I get some error details from eventviewer. If anyone faced this issue, please help me.

```
> > Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
> Info: System.NullReferenceException Stack:    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToolBarPanel.MeasureGeneratedItems(Boolean,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Double, System.Windows.Size ByRef,
> Double ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToolBarPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBarPanel.MeasureWithCollapsePrevention(System.Windows.Size)
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBarPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)  
> at
> System.Windows.Controls.ToolBar.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)  
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.ToolBarTray.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)  
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
> System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Shell.Controls.WindowContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)   
> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Process_WM_SIZE(System.Windows.UIElement,
> IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.LayoutFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32,
> IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean
> ByRef)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
> System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)  
> at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32,
> IntPtr, IntPtr)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr,
> Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)    at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32,
> IntPtr, IntPtr)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr,
> Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Comment: install the update 3 and if this also doesn't fix it, try to run VS in safe ode (without any extensions): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: try to repair VS , go to 'Programs and Features'>find VS>click 'Change'>click 'Repair'

Comment: Is your Windows 10 fully up to date as well?  All updates applied?